# Laravel eloquent giving different results from DB facade

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, cross-join, laravel-facade

I have a laravel eloquent query that is giving me a different result from the same query using the `DB` facade.  I cannot understand why the result would be different.  The result set is the same length (`6`), but the one data object key `ha` stays the same for the eloquent query (which is not correct), while the DB facade returns the `ha` key values correctly.
Eloquent:

```
$add = FertilAppUser::join('farms', 'fertilappuser.farm_id', '=', 'farms.id')
            ->join('farm_blocks', 'farms.id', '=', 'farm_blocks.farm_id') 
            ->crossJoin('crops', 'farm_blocks.crop_id', '=', 'crops.id')
            ->select('fertilappuser.block_id', 'fertilappuser.id', 'farm_blocks.hectares as ha')
            ->where('fertilappuser.farm_id', '=',  16)
            ->whereNotIn('fertilappuser.block_id', [6])
            ->groupBy('fertilappuser.id')
            ->get();
```

The eloquent query returns a Collection of 6 object items, but the `ha` key stays the same:

```
                    Collection {
                        #items: array:6 [
                          0 =>  {
                            #original: array:3 [
                              "block_id" => 140
                              "id" => 7
                              "ha" => 2.5 // does not vary
                            ]
                          }
                          1 =>  {
                            #original: array:3 [
                              "block_id" => 809
                              "id" => 66
                              "ha" => 2.5 // does not vary
                            ]
                          }
                          2 =>  {
                            #original: array:3 [
                              "block_id" => 152
                              "id" => 67
                              "ha" => 2.5 // does not vary
                            ]
                          }
                          3 =>  {
                            #original: array:3 [
                              "block_id" => 143
                              "id" => 68
                              "ha" => 2.5 // does not vary
                            ]
                          }
                          4 =>  {
                            #original: array:3 [
                              "block_id" => 149
                              "id" => 69
                              "ha" => 2.5 // does not vary
                            ]
                          }
                          5 =>  {
                            #original: array:3 [
                              "block_id" => 673
                              "id" => 70
                              "ha" => 2.5 // does not vary
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
```

DB facade:

```
$add = DB::select('SELECT fau.id id, fau.block_id, frm_b.hectares ha ' .
        ' FROM fertilappuser as fau ' .
        ' INNER JOIN farms AS f ' .
            ' ON (fau.farm_id = f.id) ' .
        ' INNER JOIN farm_blocks as frm_b CROSS JOIN crops c ' .
            ' ON (fau.block_id = frm_b.id AND frm_b.crop_id = c.id) ' .
        ' WHERE fau.farm_id = ? AND fau.block_id NOT IN (?) ' .
        ' GROUP BY fau.id ', [16, '6']);
```

The `DB` facade returns an array of length 6 and the associated object key `ha` values vary and are correct.

```
array:6 [
  0 => {#985
    +"id": 7
    +"block_id": 140
    +"ha": 2.5 // correct
  }
  1 => {#983
    +"id": 66
    +"block_id": 809
    +"ha": null // correct
  }
  2 => {#988
    +"id": 67
    +"block_id": 152
    +"ha": null // correct
  }
  3 => {#1021
    +"id": 68
    +"block_id": 143
    +"ha": 4.3 // correct
  }
  4 => {#1022
    +"id": 69
    +"block_id": 149
    +"ha": 3.5
  }
  5 => {#1023
    +"id": 70
    +"block_id": 673
    +"ha": 2.53 // correct
  }
]
```

Does anyone know why there are differing results?  Is my joins on the eloquent query maybe incorrect?

Laravel 5.6.39

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query with eloquent is converted to the following SQL code:

```sql
select
    `fertilappuser`.`block_id`,
    `fertilappuser`.`id`,
    `farm_blocks`.`hectares` as `ha`
from
    `fertilappuser`
inner join
    `farms` on `fertilappuser`.`farm_id` = `farms`.`id`
inner join
    `farm_blocks` on `farms`.`id` = `farm_blocks`.`farm_id`
cross join
    `crops` on `farm_blocks`.`crop_id` = `crops`.`id`
where
    `fertilappuser`.`farm_id` = ?
and
    `fertilappuser`.`block_id` not in (?)
group by
    `fertilappuser`.`id`
```

Your SQL differs in some parts:

1. (probable culprit) `' INNER JOIN farm_blocks as frm_b CROSS JOIN crops c ' .`
2. (probably less important) You're passing `'6'` instead of `6`)
3. (not important at all) Aliases

Now, I'm not sure which query is correct, but basically different queries implies different results.

---

Just using the console (`php artisan tinker`) I was able to produce the following query (no setup needed since I'm not actually hitting any database)

```sql
select
    `fau`.`id` as `id`,
    `fau`.`block_id`,
    `frm_b`.`hectares` as `ha`
from
    `fertilappuser` as `fau`
inner join
    `farms` as `f` on (
        `fau`.`farm_id` = `f`.`id`
    )
inner join
    `farm_blocks` as `frm_b`
cross join
    `crops` as `c` on (
        `fau`.`block_id` = `frm_b`.`id` and `frm_b`.`crop_id` = `c`.`id`
    )
where `fau`.`farm_id` = ?
and `fau`.`block_id` not in (?)
group by `fau`.`id`
```

By running this code:

```php
// You should be able to replace the first line by either
// DB::table('fertilappuser', 'fau')
// or FertilAppUser::from('fertilappuser', 'fau')
// to keep the alias
DB::connection('mysql')->table('fertilappuser', 'fau')
    ->select('fau.id as id', 'fau.block_id', 'frm_b.hectares as ha')
    ->join('farms as f', function ($join) {
        return $join->on(['fau.farm_id' => 'f.id']);
    })
    ->join('farm_blocks as frm_b', function ($join) {
        return $join;
    })
    ->crossJoin('crops as c', function ($join) {
        return $join->on(['fau.block_id' => 'frm_b.id', 'frm_b.crop_id' => 'c.id']);
    })
    ->where('fau.farm_id', 16)
    ->whereNotIn('fau.block_id', ['6']) // I still think this should be just 6
    ->groupBy('fau.id')
    ->toSql(); // replace with ->get(); to get the results
```

Some weird things here:

- Using array notations in the $joins.

Usually you'd write

```
$join->on(['fau.farm_id' => 'f.id'])

$join->on(['fau.block_id' => 'frm_b.id', 'frm_b.crop_id' => 'c.id'])
```

as

```
$join->on('fau.farm_id', 'f.id')

$join->on('fau.block_id', 'frm_b.id')->on('frm_b.crop_id', 'c.id')
```

but using the array notation tells eloquent to put a pair of parenthesis around it. I'm not sure if it actually helps your query or not but I wanted it to be exactly the same.

- The `inner join` without `on`

Since Eloquent forces you to add a condition when using the `join()` method, I just passed a closure and made it return the `$join` itself without adding anything.

Comment: Thank you.  How did you output the query from eloquent into SQL syntax? You are right I believe with your assessment at bullet number 1.  How do I write that query `' INNER JOIN farm_blocks as frm_b CROSS JOIN crops c ' ` in eloquent?

Comment: Simply change `get()` to `toSql()` at the end of your query. Instead of a collection, you'll get a string with the sql. It's the best way to make sure you're getting the query you want if you're trying to convert a query into eloquent.

Comment: Thanks again.  How do you write in eloquent this part `' INNER JOIN farm_blocks as frm_b CROSS JOIN crops c '`.  I have tried this `->join('farm_blocks', function ($join) { $join->on( 'farms.id', '=', 'farm_blocks.farm_id')->crossJoin('crops', 'farm_blocks.crop_id', '=', 'crops.id') }) `, but I get an error.  Can you make that part of your answer please?

Comment: Without knowing the exact error there's little I can do to help. In any case, I've edited the answer with the query builder code needed to reproduce your query.

Comment: Maybe your error was simply that you forgot adding `;` near the end `'crops.id'); })`

Comment: No my eloquent version of the `crossJoin` gives a `Syntax error or access violation` error.  Your query on the other hand worked perfectly thank you.  Just one correction when using `from` it should be `from('fertilappuser as fau')`.  Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Did the query I posted in the answer work for you? What laravel version are you using?

Comment: Yes it did.  Thank you.  You are a wizard and know what you are talking about.  Laravel 5.6.39.  Added version to my question also.